# Hibernate : How can I override @Id with @EmbeddedId in subclass entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new in hibernate, and just learning it.
I created a small hospital model that has a generic base entity and I want to extend all entities from that class but when I created an entity has composite id I'v got a problem for override id attribute. How can I handle this?

my base entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<I extends Serializable> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private I id;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        BaseEntity<?> that = (BaseEntity<?>) o;
        if (id == null && that.id == null)
            return false;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

my embeddable class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class VisitId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "DOCTOR_ID")
    private Integer doctorId;

    @Column(name = "VISIT_DATE")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "VISIT_TIME")
    private Time time;
}
```

my entity that I can't extend from BaseEntity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "VISIT")
public class Visit {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VisitId visitId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCTOR_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Doctor doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PATIENT_ID")
    private Patient patient;
}
```

can any one help me to resolve this please?

With @XtremeBaumer comment I changed my Visit entity like this and it works fine:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "VISIT")
public class Visit extends BaseEntity<VisitId> {

    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id"))
    @EmbeddedId
    private VisitId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCTOR_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Doctor doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PATIENT_ID")
    private Patient patient;
}
```

So is there other way to override `getId();` method instead of overriding field?

Comment: Try `@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id"))` over `@EmbeddedId`

Comment: Thanks a lot  @XtremeBaumer it worked fine but is there a way to use getter to map that?

Comment: I wouldn't mix annotations on fields with annotations on getter/setter. I generally find it easier with annotations on fields. I don't think there is any benefit to have annotations on getter/setter

Comment: So I'm going to use your solution. thanks for your helping :)

Comment: It's a pity but BaseEntity is not a correct approach in general. Please, check https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ for beginning